# Can't finish install, getting error

Tags: install

I am receiving this error when installing via shell:

PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types'

PHP Fatal error:  Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL

Each error references "Bootup.php on line 3" and "Bootup.php on line 24" respectively.

I am running php v7.2

Comment: Are you sure CLI is on 7.2? What do you get if you run `php -v`?

Comment: @Oli I'm on php 7.4 and -v from the command line gives 7.4 (cli). I was wondering the converse - perhaps e.g. bash scripts are not running with the cli version but another?